# Current Menu Item not working with $childpages

Tags: php, wordpress, class, menu

I need to add the "active" or "current-menu-item" class to a custom childpages menu. I've tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

I've browsed google but can't find anything that will work!

```
<?php
$childpages = query_posts('orderby=menu_order&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent=35&posts_per_page=300');
if ($childpages)
{
    // Display the children content
    foreach ($childpages as $post)
    {
        setup_postdata($post)
        ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="mezzanine-sub-title <?php echo!empty($_GET['page_id']) && $_GET['page_id'] == $post->ID ? "active" : NULL ?>">
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <a>
                <?php
                global $post;
                $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(5600, 1000), false, '');
                ?>
                <div class="mezzanine-sub-image" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );border:<?php the_field('border'); ?>;">
                </div>
            </a>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `query_posts` to `get_posts` also you have invalid syntax with your `<a>` tag.

finally instead of using `$get` which is not returning anything use `wp_query`

so your code should be:

```
$childpages = get_posts('orderby=menu_order&order=asc&post_type=page&post_parent=35&posts_per_page=300');
    if ($childpages)
    {
        // Display the children content
        foreach ($childpages as $post)
        {
            setup_postdata($post)
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="mezzanine-sub-title<?php if ( $post->ID == $wp_query->post->ID ) { echo ' active'; }?>">
                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    <?php
                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array(5600, 1000), false, '');
                    ?>
                    <div class="mezzanine-sub-image" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );border:<?php the_field('border'); ?>;">
                    </div>

            </a>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. One last thing. Do you know how to get it to automatically get the post parent id instead of having to type it in every template?

Comment: In custom templates but I would like to be able to use this as a generic template for children pages that doesn't need the ID putting in every time if that makes sense?

Comment: `$post->post_parent` gets you the parent post so you could do - `$post_data = get_post($post->post_parent); $parent_ID = $post_data->ID;`

Comment: Thanks for this, where should I put that in the code sorry?

Comment: Sorry I meant where do I put the amendment you made in that PHP above?